# how to use "current() [name()='merge:change']" type of statement in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hi,
            This is a XML that i am working on, I need to access a specific data please help Desired output is: Hello_World

```
<catalog 
    xmlns:merge="http://www.merge.org/change" >
    <cd>
        <title>
            <a>Empire Burlesque</a>
            <b>Manik</b>
        </title>
        <artist>       
            <a>Bob Dylan</a>
            <b>Aayush</b>
        </artist>
        <country>       
            <note>
                <para>A small quantity of hydraulic fluid on the inner cylinder is satisfactory 
                    <merge:change>Hello_World
                    </merge:change>
                </para>
            </note>
        </country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Now I want to access the content written in merge:change tag using functions like current() [name()='merge:change']"

I have written this XSL: but i am not getting any output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:merge="http://www.merge.org/change">

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <xsl:for-each select="cd/country">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()/note/para [name()='merge:change']"/>
            <br/>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone please help ??

Desired output is :

```
Hello_World
```

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="note/para/merge:change"/>` should do the job.

Comment: Hi potame, Thanx for your reply.  Could you please tell me how to use "current()/note/para [name()='merge:change']"   this type of function. Actually I need to use functions to access that content of merge:change.

Comment: that is not a function but most probably a predicate

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<xsl:value-of select="current()/note/para [name()='merge:change']"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="current()/note/para/*[name()='merge:change']"/>
```

the expression `para/*[name()='merge:change']` means a child of para named `merge:change`

Comment: The `current()` part is redundant.

Comment: Yes it is. I have retained that part because it is included in his question.